# Dynamic publishing swfobject external interface callback method undefined

Tags: actionscript, callback, swfobject, externalinterface

Could some genius help on this issue to sort it out!!! It will be much appreciated

Actually I have flash music player loaded by means of config file named config.xml

**Flash player Action script example**

```
**myUltimateMp3Player.loadConfig("config.xml");**

import flash.external.ExternalInterface; 
stop();
// ExternalInterface receive
if (ExternalInterface.available) { 
   ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendTextFromHtml", null, function(val:String):Void {    
   myUltimateMp3Player.loadConfig(val); }); 
}
```

I'm tried to embed the flash dynamically using Swf object,so when a click event handled from a list from html, the corresponding config.xml should be loaded on the flash player.

**Sample HTML code:**

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#Musiclist li", function() {    
    var c = "youtube-playlist";
    $("#media-" + c).remove();
    createMedia(c);
    var id=this.id;
    var idxml=id+".xml";
    var swfPanel="media-" + c;
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    params.swliveconnect = "true";
    params.allowfullscreen = "true";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "flashobj";
    attributes.name = "flashobj";
    swfobject.embedSWF("source.swf", "flashcontent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes,callbackFn);
});
```

**callback function**

```
//This function is invoked by SWFObject once the <object> has been created
var callbackFn = function (e){
    //Only execute if SWFObject embed was successful
    if(!e.success || !e.ref){ return false; }
    swfLoadEvent(function(){
       var obj=e.ref;
       obj.sendTextFromHtml("config.xml");
       alert("The SWF has finished loading!");
    });
};
```

**Function to hold timer for SWF's PercentLoaded value and waits until it hits "100"**

```
function swfLoadEvent(fn){
  //Ensure fn is a valid function
  if(typeof fn !== "function"){ return false; }

    //This timeout ensures we don't try to access PercentLoaded too soon
    var initialTimeout = setTimeout(function (){
    //Ensure Flash Player's PercentLoaded method is available and returns a value
    if(typeof e.ref.PercentLoaded !== "undefined" && e.ref.PercentLoaded()){
        //Set up a timer to periodically check value of PercentLoaded
        var loadCheckInterval = setInterval(function (){
            //Once value == 100 (fully loaded) we can do whatever we want
            if(e.ref.PercentLoaded() === 100){
                //Execute function
                fn();
                //Clear timer
                clearInterval(loadCheckInterval);
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
}, 200);}
```

---

So I cant figure it out what I'm doing wrong,

The error getting was,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

If I'm not using the swfLoadEvent Timer,

The error getting was,

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'sendTextFromHtml'

Answer (score 0):

`e` is not a global variable. try modifying your `swfLoadEvent` function to pass a reference to the swf as an argument:

```
function swfLoadEvent(swf, fn){
    swf.sendTextFromHtml("config.xml");
    ...
}
```

which then gets invoked as

```
swfLoadEvent(e.ref, function(){
    ...
});
```